# manual sharing doesn't work

Tags: sharing, sharing-rule

i try to  share a record with manual sharing "sharing button" and give to another user the access level :"Read/Write" .
the problem is: this user can just view a record but can't edit .

for information : user has already "read" on this object .

Comment: Does user have Object Level Security and Field Level Security for that object ?

Comment: Yes, Read and Edit on the all field .

Comment: but what about object? not field level but object level?

Comment: he has Read on object and on tab

Comment: but edit? Does it have edit?

Comment: no ?
he must  get Edit ?

Comment: yes. Otherwise user would not be able to edit it. There is a difference between sharing and OLS/FLS. User may be able to edit and read record, but not being able to see all records because those are not shared, or viceversa as in your example . Good image here  - https://res.cloudinary.com/hy4kyit2a/image/upload/v1455065050/doc/trailhead/images/adg_security_sharing_concepts.jpg

Answer (score 1):

i think i get it.
So thought that user can has only Read access on the object .
And with manual sharing if i give him Read/Write on record he can edit/view a record .
But it's not true, if i well understand he must have Edit access.
And  Even he has Edit on object he couldn't see or edit the Record if the record is not shared with "level read/write"

Answer (score 0):

**To grant access to a record, you must be one of the following users.
The record owner**
1)A user in a role above the owner in the hierarchy (if your organization’s sharing settings control access through hierarchies)

2)Any user granted “Full Access” to the record

3)An administrator

You can also refer https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=granting_access_to_records.htm&language=en

Hope this help you.

Let me know for any questions....HAPPY TO HELP YOU :)

Comment: i'm admin , and owner of record and also i have full access to the  all object .

Comment: Can you tell me which record you are sharing?

Comment: custom object called 'test' , and i create some record, when click on sharing button and to choose a user i give read/write access level .
but user can't see Edit button, he can only view a record .

Comment: Have a look through the documentation here https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=dev_security.htm